# Unity, problem with android build on 120hz devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, refresh, frame

I'm working on simple 2d project, sprites run from top to bottom and on standard phones (60hz) everything look smooth, but on s20+ (exynos 990 version) with 120hz on, sprites start gently tug, jumps, loosing smoothness. when i turn off 120hz refresh rate, game work perfect. at first move was based on while loop with `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` and that was causing another problem. if it was based on frames whole move was 2x faster, and game was unplayable.
so i decided to build movement on `void Update()`, and turn on vSync, that solve 2x speed problem but it doesn't help with smooth lose,

I was trying to limit frame rate to 60 by `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;` with vSync on 0, same result.

so my question is: Is there any possibility to do something with it? Can i somehow tell phone to turn off 120hz refresh for time when my app is running? or maybe there is some option in unity settings that i don't know about, which can solve my misery. I'm really on the edge of mental breakdown now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (to turn on 120hz display mode):

1. Create file "MainActivity.java" in Assets folder.
2. Open this file and paste code:

```
package com.*YOUR COMPANY NAME*.*YOUR PRODUCT NAME*;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams p = w.getAttributes();
            Display.Mode[] modes = getDisplay().getSupportedModes();
            //find display mode with max hz
            int maxMode = 0;
            float maxHZ = 60f;
            for(Display.Mode m:modes) {
                if (maxHZ < m.getRefreshRate()) {
                    maxHZ = m.getRefreshRate();
                    maxMode = m.getModeId();
                }
            }
            p.preferredDisplayModeId = maxMode;
            w.setAttributes(p);
        }
  }
}
```

3. Change `*YOUR COMPANY NAME*` and `*YOUR PRODUCT NAME*` to Company Name and Product Name from Project Settings -> Player.
4. Go to Project Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings. Tick "Custom Main Manifest".
5. Open file "AndroidManifest.xml" in "Assets\Plugins\Android".
6. Change android:name=`com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity` to android:name=`com.*YOUR COMPANY NAME*.*YOUR PRODUCT NAME*.MainActivity`.
7. Be sure to call `Application.targetFrameRate = Screen.currentResolution.refreshRate;` in any script!

**UPDATE: FIXED BUG IN ANDROID 12.**

https://forum.unity.com/threads/set-screen-refresh-rate-on-android-11.997247/

Comment: FIXED BUG IN ANDROID 12.